# How to echo a loop of php arrays contained in a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

I have this string :

```
print_r($elements);
```

That returns this :

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => USA
            [2] => CANADA
            [3] => BRAZIL
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => MOROCCO
            [2] => ALGERIA
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => FRANCE
            [2] => BELGIUM
            [3] => SPAIN
            [4] => ITALY
        )

)
```

I would woud like to echo each of those values in the following format :

Set 1 :
1 - USA 
2 - CANADA 
3 - BRAZIL

Set 2 :
1 - MOROCCO 
2 - ALGERIA

Set 3 :
1 - FRANCE 
2 - BELGIUM 
3 - SPAIN 
4 - ITALY

What is the best way to do it ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over your arrays and use ternaries like this :

```
foreach($elements as $key => $element) {

   $tmp = '';
   foreach($element as $num => $value) {
       $tmp .= $tmp ? ' - ' : '';
       $tmp .= $num . ' - ' . $value;
   }
   echo 'Set ' . $key . ' : ' . $tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michaoj ! that worked perfectly !